# Peewee registering a new model at Runtime

Tags: python, postgresql, peewee

I want to be able to connect to database (PostgreSQL) which url and credentials are been received as parameter, without previous knowledge of the scheme. So i already know I can create new types in python like this:

```
MyModel = type('MyMdel', (peewee.Model,))
```

And then add new Peewee fields:

```
my_field = peewee.IntegerField(null=False, default=0)
my_field.add_to_class(MyModel, 'my_field_name')
```

But will this work in peewee?

Answer (score 0):

That looks correct to me. Are you experiencing any problems?